# Making divs move inside a container on click with jquery,( like a slide show )

Tags: jquery, html

Hi Im new to jquery I was hoping one of you more experienced guys could help me out. I have a container set to overflow: hidden and inside I have 3 divs and two of them are hidden because they are overflowing. I would like to make the divs all appear in order sliding from the right upon each click of the container. I have got the second div to appear on click but I cant get the third to move. each time the container is clicked the div in inside should move 100px, but it doesn't. Please explain to me why it doesn't. 
here is the JS fiddle link -> [http://jsfiddle.net/FSMMA/](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/HBHcC/)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style>
    .container{
        width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.one,.two,.three{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
    .one{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
.two{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.three{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.boxes{
    width:400px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').click(function(){
        $('.boxes').offset({left :-100})
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="one">
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving only -100, so it moves only one container, try the followinfg code, which will reduce 100 from the previous value, so it moves properly,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.container').click(function(){
    $('.boxes').offset({left : $('.boxes').offset().left-100})
    });
});
```

UPDATED FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/HBHcC/1/

Comment: It' not stoping at any point the process is going all forever. how ti stop it?

Comment: hi thanks for the response. I think I get it, for the left position for the first offset  your selecting the boxes div. then your getting the left position of the new box with the second offset. Then you put the .left and the box moves to the left 100 px on each click. I never used ".left" like that. I think I understand it so thanks for your help.

Comment: @VivekDragon Yeah we need a lot of improvements, i am just trying to give him an idea

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you prefer .animate()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.container').click(function(){
    $('.boxes').animate({"left": "-=100px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

And add this

```
.boxes{
width:400px;
position:absolute;
 }

.one,.two,.three{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
float:left;
```

}

Comment: Thanks. I was just learning about offsets so I wanted to practice with it. Again, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

To add to the provided answer... The following will give a slide effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var pos = 1;

     $('.container').click(function(){

     if(pos < 4) {
         $('.boxes div:nth-child(' + pos + ')').animate({ width: 0 }, 1000);
          pos++;
     }

    });

 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but I suspect there's a pure-CSS fix that somebody else could provide.  That said, I fiddled with the CSS *and* the JS *and* the HTML and got it working.

In the HTML, I added a **box** class to the inside most divs:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="one box"></div>
    <div class="two box"></div>
    <div class="three box"></div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

The addition of the **box** class allowed me to tidy up the CSS a bit.  That has nothing to do with your problem, but I couldn't help myself. :-)  More importantly though, notice I made the boxes float to the left.

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.one {
    background-color:green;
}

.two {
    background-color:red;
}

.three {
    background-color:blue;
}

.boxes {
    width:400px;
}​
```

In my JavaScript I'm capturing the click on the individual boxes, rather than on the container.  This allows me to detect if we're on the last box, because I assume you don't want that one to scroll off the screen.  Also, instead of changing the offset of the "**boxes**" div, I'm changing the left margin.  And finally, I switched to using animate instead of offset for two reasons:  First, I couldn't figure out how to get offset to work. ;-)  Second, you can add a delay to the animation to create a slide-in effect if you'd like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').on("click", function() {
        // Is this the last div, or is there a next one?
        if ($(this).next().length) {            
            var animSpeed = 200;  // Make this 0 for an instant change
            $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "-=100"}, animSpeed);
        }        
    });
});
```

You can demo this at http://jsfiddle.net/HBHcC/11/